# Cron is running & executing jobs, but won't output to a .log file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I realise that there are plenty of cron questions on the site and I've spent the last hour searching for a solution but haven't been able to find one. Essentially the cron job does execute, but it doesn't seem to execute or at least output the output to a file that I specify.

I can see that cron is running:

```
josh@lin-ldn-cen:~$ pgrep cron
734
```

The cron job executes successfully, as seen in my /var/log/cron file:

`Sep 26 08:34:01 lin-ldn-cen CROND[82848]: (josh) CMD (/home/josh/test_script.sh > /home/josh/cron_logs/test.log)`

I've used absolute paths as well as setting the PATH in my crontab file. I've included a newline at the end of my crontab file:

```
josh@lin-ldn-cen:~$ crontab -l
SHELL=/bin/sh PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

0 */6 * * * /home/josh/youtube-downloads/download_djdj.sh > /home/josh/cron_logs/cron_download_djdj.log
*/5 * * * * /home/josh/youtube-downloads/download_djdj.sh 2>&1 /home/josh/cron_logs/cron_download_djdj.log
* * * * * /home/josh/test_script.sh > /home/josh/cron_logs/test.log
```

(Having the path at the top hasn't made any difference at all to the execution of my script)

test_script.sh is incredibly simple, and I used absolute paths there too - here it is:

```
josh@lin-ldn-cen:~$ cat test_script.sh
#!/bin/bash/

/usr/bin/echo Hello world
```

I've also tried several other things - including a `.` before my script in the crontab file, using 2>&1 to output errors, double checked paths, double checked that the .sh file is executable with chmod +x test_script.sh, included both sh  and bash  before the command in my crontab file - none of this seems to work. All I'm expecting from this is to see 'Hello world' in /home/josh/cron_logs/test.log.

Edit: I'd like to add that this was on Debian, not Ubuntu. Apologies.

Comment: If your intention is to redirect both standard output and standard error to the log file, then your `2>&1` is in the wrong place - see for example [Tell me all about 2>&1 -- what's the difference between 2>&1 >foo and >foo 2>&1, and when do I use which?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055)

Comment: echo is placed in /bin/echo, but it´s best not to supply any path to commands if you don't have any special requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I've since realised that the .sh file was executing - it was just the output that was not executing.

I fixed this issue by adding `SHELL=/usr/bin/bash` to the top of my crontab, and by changing the relevant line to use &>> to output to a log file:

`* * * * * /home/josh/test_script.sh &>> /home/josh/cron_logs/test.log`

Credit to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52330/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-from-within-cron) - I found it after I realised that the problem was isolated to the output to file segment of my command.

Comment: On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is the same as `/bin/bash` or `/usr/bin/bash`. So that's not the reason why this didn't work.
The issue may be the line ```SHELL=/bin/sh PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin```. As this is written in a single line (and should be in two separate lines - or not present at all, as these are basically the defaults cron assumes), this may mess up things. By the way, your second command in the file contains an error, it should be: ```/home/josh/youtube-downloads/download_djdj.sh > /home/josh/cron_logs/cron_download_djdj.log 2>&1```

Comment: @raj Please consider writing an answer - I agree with almost everything except your first assertion (afaik `/bin/sh` is the same as `/bin/dash` in all current Ubuntu releases, and `/usr/bin/bash` may or may not exist at all, depending whether `/bin` is symlinked to `usr/bin`).

Comment: I was so used to the fact that `/bin/sh` was for long time symlinked to `/bin/bash` that I didn't ever check it when I installed the new Ubuntu version... You are right, `/bin/sh` is `/bin/dash` now. I wonder what are actual syntax differences between `bash` and `dash`, ie. how big is the chance that a script written with `bash` in mind won't work under `dash`...